# Pass Object Data to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, object, bootstrap-modal

I'm looking to pass the JavaScript Object data to each of the Object's particular Modal window, when a user clicks the available button. However, when I test and click the button, two things happen. First, nothing shows up, and if something does show up it will be the same data for each Modal, usually the last object's data.

```js
var radio = [
    {
        name:"106 power",
        address:"1620 sw 11th st",
        phone:"305-892-9927"
    },
    {
        name:"99 jamz",
        address:"1900 sw 19th st",
        phone:"305-892-9900"
    },
 {
        name:"cool jamz",
        address:"3450 sw 167th st",
        phone:"304-892-9900"
    }

    ]

    for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){

    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += '<div class="box2">' + 
    radio[i].name + '<br>' + radio[i].address + '<br> <button type="button class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Click me! </button></div>';

    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").on('click',function(){
       $("#main-content").html('<div class="box3">' + radio[i].name + '<br>' + 
    radio[i].address + '<br>' + radio[i].phone + '</div>');
  
    });
    
});
```

```css
.box{
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:grey;
    }
    .box2{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:white;
    }
    .box3{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en-US">

    <head>


    <title>Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-    
    2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>
     


    <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="box" class="box"></div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;            
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body " id="main-content">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal')` to catch event when modal is shown and use `e.relatedTarget` to get the current button you click

I added `data-index` to the button, so we can get current radio

```js
var radio = [
    {
        name:"106 power",
        address:"1620 sw 11th st",
        phone:"305-892-9927"
    },
    {
        name:"99 jamz",
        address:"1900 sw 19th st",
        phone:"305-892-9900"
    },
 {
        name:"cool jamz",
        address:"3450 sw 167th st",
        phone:"304-892-9900"
    }

    ]

    for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){

    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += '<div class="box2">' + 
    radio[i].name + '<br>' + radio[i].address + '<br> <button type="button class="button" data-index="' + i + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Click me! </button></div>';

    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var i = $(e.relatedTarget).data('index');
      console.log(i);
      $("#main-content").html('<div class="box3">' + radio[i].name + '<br>' + 
    radio[i].address + '<br>' + radio[i].phone + '</div>');
  })
    
});
```

```css
.box{
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:grey;
    }
    .box2{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:white;
    }
    .box3{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en-US">

    <head>


    <title>Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-    
    2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>
     


    <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="box" class="box"></div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;            
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body " id="main-content">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```